# How to make upload operation display on right click menu in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

The version of my Pycharm IDE is 2018.3. And as the following picture, it does not display upload operation by default. I want to make it display. And I remember that in earlier versions, upload operation displayed on the menu by default.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the menu as you want, see **Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Menus and Toolbars**:

[image]

I added **Upload** to **Project View Popup Menu**. Now the result menu (assuming you have a deployment configured):

[image]

Comment: thanks for your kind answer, but how did you add "Upload" to "Project View Popup Menu"? I found I cannot do it in my IDE...